# Remove license check from script code in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a script in Codeigniter which includes a line of code automatically. I have tried to remove it many times but it's not being removed.

```
<script>
   $(function(){
      $.getScript("https://activeitzone.com/check/shop.js");
   });

</script>
```

This line of code is automatically included at the end of page and out of the tag.

Comment: You must purchase a licence rather than HACK the code. Please remove this question!

Answer (score 1):

A simple change can help to By-Pass CI Licence check.

Go to **System > Core > config.php and remove**

```
if ($index == '')
{
return base64_decode('PHNjcmlwdD4kKGZ1bmN0aW9uKCl7JC5nZXRTY3JpcHQoImh0dHBzOi8vYWN0aXZlaXR6b25lLmNvbS9jaGVjay9zaG9wLmpzIik7fSk7PC9zY3JpcHQ+');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a script automatically added by the [Active Super Shop Multi-Vendor System](http://activeitzone.com/active_supershop/landing/) package to check the license.

I found that out by reading [this discussion board](https://codecanyon.net/item/active-super-shop-multivendor-cms/12124432/comments?page=44) (on page 44 of the 1172 comments as the time of this writing).

Abbreviated discussion...

> peddareddy PURCHASED 3 months ago
>   $(function(){$.getScript(“https://activeitzone.com/check/shop.js”);});$(function(){$.getScript(“https://activeitzone.com/check/shop.js”);});
>
> How to remove this code. And where it was located. It keep checking my
>   website weather it was activated or not even i have entered the
>   purchase code

:

> ActiveITzone AUTHOR 3 months ago Hello, the code you mentioned does
>   not hamper the site speed. It is just a license check so that the
>   product is not used beyond legality :) Therefore, we shall not remove
>   the script. Thanks!

Comment: So there is no way to remove this line ?

Comment: It's a jQuery script that checks the server to see if it's licensed. So even if you somehow defeated the ajax check with another js script and removed the message I'm guessing the server would still know it's unlicensed and it would probably reject any forms submissions from the shopping cart, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following lines in **System > Core > config.php**

```
if ($index == '')
{
    return base64_decode('PHNjcmlwdD4kKGZ1bmN0aW9uKCl7JC5nZXRTY3JpcHQoImh0dHBzOi8vYWN0aXZlaXR6b25lLmNvbS9jaGVjay9zaG9wLmpzIik7fSk7PC9zY3JpcHQ+');
}
```

And enjoy the active sh